# Como posso ajustar o meu chat feito em html e css?

Tags: php, html, jquery, css

A minha caixa de mensagens como visto no primeiro print, está lá em cima no topo, quero deixar-lo lá em baixo onde normalmente fica, mas não sei como. Agradeço qualquer ajuda possível! 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title> </title>
  <link href="bia.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js" > </script>
</head>

  <body>
    <div id="site" >

      <div id="topo">
        <h1>Corpo</h1>
      </div>
      <div id="conteudo">
        <h1>Conteudo</h1>

      </div>
      <div id="chat">
        <form method="post">
          <input type="text" name="mensagem" id="mensagem" placeholder="Digite sua mensagem..." maxlength="100" autocomplete="off" />
        </form>
       </div>
      <div id="perfis">
        <h1>Perfis</h1>
      </div>
      <div id="jogos">
        <h1>Jogos</h1>
      </div>

    </div>


  </body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
* { margic:0; padding:0; border:0}

body{background: #000000}
div#site{ background: #999999; width: 990px; height: 1200px; margin: auto; padding: 5px;}
div#topo{ background: #333333; height: 120px;}
div#conteudo{ background: #333333; height: 500px; width: 730px; margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px; float:left; border: 1px solid #ddd; border-radius: 15px;}
div#chat { background: #333; height: 500px; margin-top: 5px; width: 235px; float:right; overflow: auto; overflow-x: hidden; border-radius: 15px; border: 1px solid #ddd;}
input[type='text']{display: block; width: 233px; font-size: 14px; padding:5px;margin:1px; border-color: #ffffff; border-radius: 15px;}
div#perfis{ background: #333333; height: 80px; width: 990px; clear: both;}
div#jogos { background: #333333; height: 450px; width: 990px;}
```

Comment: Cara, coloque o código em forma de texto na pergunta, e não como uma imagem, pq não tem como copiar.

Comment: Perdão, acabei de editar com o código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use flexbox na `div#chat` com orientação de coluna e use `margin-top: auto` no `form` que ele ficará na parte de baixo da div.

Adicione as propriedades na `div#chat`:

```
display: flex; flex-direction: column;
```

E crie um estilo para o form:

```
#chat form{
   margin-top: auto;
}
```

Veja:

```css
* { margin: 0; padding:0; border:0}

body{background: #000000}
div#site{ background: #999999; width: 990px; height: 1200px; margin: auto; padding: 5px;}
div#topo{ background: #333333; height: 120px;}
div#conteudo{ background: #333333; height: 500px; width: 730px; margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px; float:left; border: 1px solid #ddd; border-radius: 15px;}
div#chat { display: flex; flex-direction: column; background: #333; height: 500px; margin-top: 5px; width: 235px; float:right; overflow: auto; overflow-x: hidden; border-radius: 15px; border: 1px solid #ddd;}
input[type='text']{display: block; width: 233px; font-size: 14px; padding:5px;margin:1px; border-color: #ffffff; border-radius: 15px;}
div#perfis{ background: #333333; height: 80px; width: 990px; clear: both;}
div#jogos { background: #333333; height: 450px; width: 990px;}

#chat form{
   margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="site" >

   <div id="topo">
     <h1>Corpo</h1>
   </div>
   <div id="conteudo">
     <h1>Conteudo</h1>

   </div>
   <div id="chat">
     <form method="post">
       <input type="text" name="mensagem" id="mensagem" placeholder="Digite sua mensagem..." maxlength="100" autocomplete="off" />
     </form>
    </div>
   <div id="perfis">
     <h1>Perfis</h1>
   </div>
   <div id="jogos">
     <h1>Jogos</h1>
   </div>

 </div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!!!

Answer (score 0):

O que você pode fazer é adicionar o form a uma div

```html
<div id="chat">
            <div id="mensagem">
                <form method="post">
                    <input type="text" name="mensagem" placeholder="Digite sua mensagem..." maxlength="100"
                        autocomplete="off" />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

atribuir a ele a id mensagem que você tinha atribuido anteriormente ao input, e depois disso você define essa div como

```css
        div#mensagem {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0px;
        }
```

não esquecendo de tornar a div#chat position:relative;

```css
        div#chat {
            background: #333;
            height: 500px;
            margin-top: 5px;
            width: 235px;
            float: right;
            overflow: auto;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            border-radius: 15px;
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            position: relative;
        }
```

sendo assim você torna o elemento "mensagem" absoluto em seu posicionamento, porem ele vai estar de certa forma linkado a div chat.

```css
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            border: 0
        }

        body {
            background: #000000
        }

        div#site {
            background: #999999;
            width: 990px;
            height: 1200px;
            margin: auto;
            padding: 5px;
        }

        div#topo {
            background: #333333;
            height: 120px;
        }

        div#conteudo {
            background: #333333;
            height: 500px;
            width: 730px;
            margin-top: 5px;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            float: left;
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            border-radius: 15px;
        }

        div#chat {
            background: #333;
            height: 500px;
            margin-top: 5px;
            width: 235px;
            float: right;
            overflow: auto;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            border-radius: 15px;
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            position: relative;
        }

        input[type='text'] {
            display: block;
            width: 233px;
            font-size: 14px;
            padding: 5px;
            margin: 1px;
            border-color: #ffffff;
            border-radius: 15px;
        }

        div#perfis {
            background: #333333;
            height: 80px;
            width: 990px;
            clear: both;
        }

        div#jogos {
            background: #333333;
            height: 450px;
            width: 990px;
        }


        div#mensagem {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0px;
        }
    </style>
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title> </title>
    <link href="bia.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"> </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="site">

        <div id="topo">
            <h1>Corpo</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="conteudo">
            <h1>Conteudo</h1>

        </div>
        <div id="chat">
            <div id="mensagem">
                <form method="post">
                    <input type="text" name="mensagem" placeholder="Digite sua mensagem..." maxlength="100"
                        autocomplete="off" />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="perfis">
            <h1>Perfis</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="jogos">
            <h1>Jogos</h1>
        </div>

    </div>


</body>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!!!!